# Append data from an existing mdb into another existing mdb

Tags: database-design, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm upgrading an existing front-end and back-end set of mdbs.  The back-end is getting bloated and impacting performance.  Data more than two years old still needs to be retained, but is unlikely to ever actually be accessed again.  My thinking is that it would be appropriate to have an active back-end (i.e., only current and the previous year's worth of data) and an archived back-end (i.e., at the beginning of each year, append all data from the active back-end into the existing, archived back-end).

- What other approaches I should be considering?
- If this is an appropriate approach, how do I append all the data from the active back-end mdb into the archive back-end, preferably from the front-end (e.g., a start-up function)?

  - The only method that I've been able to identify, is to go into the archive back-end, import every table from the active back-end, then do an append.  Is there a way to do all of this from the front-end?

Comment: How big is the back-end data file? If it's under 1GB I would suggest you have no reason whatsoever to archive. If it's slow, then you probably need to do two things, set up regular maintenance (so it's compacted regularly) and implement proper indexing.

Comment: (a) Unfortunately, I'm unable to run regular maintenance.  (b) Based on conversations with the intermediaries, neither the intermediaries or daily users can troubleshoot even the most rudimentary of problems (e.g., fixing a typo on a form).  (c) Several years back, I actually ran into huge, repeated problems with Access' compact and repair.  (d) The back-end is approaching 1GB.  Put all this together, and I'm really hesitant to try to implement any type of regular maintenance.

Comment: I am going to be available when they deploy the updated front-end, and I'm hoping that at that time I can also talk them through a compact and repair.  But I've got to implement something that is requires the least user intervention and least room for problems.  If I can get an archiving routine to run automatically once each year, I think that will resolve their immediate issues, with the least probability of introducing new issues.

Comment: As for implementing proper indexing - I've been refactoring as I go.  Frustratingly, it would take more time than the client will allocate to fix several key areas.

Comment: If you can't implement proper maintenance of your Jet/ACE database, then you really shouldn't be using that as a data store. If it's uncompacted, a size approaching 1GB doesn't mean anything at all -- if it's badly designed, that could just be due to normal bloat during append/delete operations (which shouldn't be in the back end -- that would be part of the "badly designed" component). But if regular maintenance is not possible, then how could you upsize to SQL Server and run its regular maintenance?

Comment: In short, I'd say your clients need a come-to-Jesus moment where you educate them on the fact that they are not acting as though their data has any value at all. This has nothing at all to do with the archiving issue -- if they aren't doing regular maintenance on the back end and making regular backups, they are screwed if anything goes wrong. Upsizing to SQL Server won't really fix that if they don't implement regular maintenance and backup on their SQL Server. Of course, the required administrative operations on a Jet/ACE back end are just as scriptable as with SQL Server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned bloating.  Run Compact and Repair on the bloated back-end MDB, if you haven't already.  In addition to shrinking the file size, it will also update index statistics which can allow the query optimizer to make better decisions about your query plans.

You didn't provide details about your existing databases and tables, so I made several simplifying assumptions.

1. Your front-end MDB contains links to all of the tables in the back-end MDB which you want to archive.
2. All the front-end links are links to only those tables.  (IOW, no links to tables which you don't want to archive.
3. The link names match the table names in the back-end mdb.
4. Your tables all include a date field named "date_field".  (This is the field whose values will be used to determine which records get archived.)
5. You have created an archive database, C:\db\archive.mdb, which includes empty copies of all the tables you want to archive.  You may want to convert autonumber fields to long integer.  Also if you're not anticipating the archived data will be hardly ever used, you could drop all the indexes (which include primary keys, unique constraints, and relationships) ... there could be considerable space savings if you care ... but also inserting the data can be much faster when you don't have indexes to update.

So I will suggest making a copy of your back-end database, then give this procedure a try.  Look in the Immediate Window to check the INSERT and DELETE statements.  If they look reasonable uncomment the two CurrentDb.Execute lines and see what happens.  (You DID make a backup first, right?)

```
Public Sub DoArchive()
    Const cstrArchive As String = "C:\db\archive.mdb"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strAppend As String
    Dim strCutoff As String
    Dim strDelete As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set db = CurrentDb
    strCutoff = "#" & Year(Date) - 1 & "/01/01#"
    strWhere = " WHERE date_field < " & strCutoff
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            strAppend = "INSERT INTO [" & tdf.name & "] IN '" & _
                cstrArchive & "' SELECT * FROM [" & tdf.name & _
                "]" & strWhere & ";"
            Debug.Print strAppend
            ''CurrentDb.Execute strAppend, dbFailOnError
            strDelete = "DELETE FROM [" & tdf.name & "]" & _
                strWhere & ";"
            Debug.Print strDelete
            ''CurrentDb.Execute strDelete, dbFailOnError
        End If
    Next tdf

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.description _
        & ") in procedure DoArchive"
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: @HansUp - thanks for giving me hope that I'm not crazy.

Assumptions 1, 2, & 3 - yes

Comment: Assumption 4 - I wish!  Basically, they break down into four types: FY field (text), date field (date/time), simple look-up tables that won't change much, complex look-up tables that will change existing records but have no versioning.  I'll come back to this one.

Assumption 5 - Basically yes. This is a database that gets passed from one poor programmer to another whenever enough problems become apparent.  So I don't want to handicap the next poor sap by removing or altering primary keys.

Comment: I spliced the functionality you proposed into functions that deal with the mess that follows from Assumption 4; with a couple of key problems, that I've been trying to overcome all day.   If I try to archive only the tables that have either a FY or date field, I get a Run-time error '3201' You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblTableName'.

Comment: So I decided to run through the non-FY/date containing tables, clear all the records from the archived back end, then copy in all the records from the active front end, but then - no matter what I've tried - I get a Run-time error '3061' "Too few parameters. Expected 1." for the non-FY/date containing tables.  (And still have the 3201 error when I do manage to get it to work for the FY/date containing tables.)  I've tried calling the .Execute (from the CurrentDB and the archived back end) AND (with and without the dbFailOnError).

Comment: Shooting myself - I went to copy the sql statements into another comment, and realized that there was an extra quote.  Extra quote removed, and the non-FY/date containing table sql statements will run. Problem solved.

Comment: Good!  Yeah, I figured Assumption #4 could be a real challenge ... but not for me because I simplified it for myself.  :-)  Good luck with this.

Comment: Assumption #4 is definitely a challenge, but it's no where near as bad as getting the tables moved in an order that won't cause the 3201 error (i.e., related record is required).

Comment: In that case I'll suggest a table of link names which includes another column to indicate the order in which they should be processed.  Then, instead of iterating through the TableDefs, use a recordset based on this new table to drive the procedure.  I'm assuming the ordering problem is for the DELETEs from the source MDB; I don't see why you should even need relationships in the archive MDB.  Another approach would be to drop the relationships before your archive operation, then re-create them afterward.  It could work, but think I'd prefer a separate table to drive this.

Comment: Brilliant!  The back-end actually did have relationships, I'm just verifying that deleting them doesn't compromise the use of the front-end to access the data.  I was still debating the best method of ordering the deleting on the active database, but none of my ideas were as clean as a table of link names.

Comment: I would vote again for no archiving. I would also point out that if you're deleting large batches of records for archiving, you have now put your database in a state that will guarantee bad performance unless you back it up and run a compact on it. This is automatable as part of the archive process, but the point is that if you can do it here, you can do it as part of a regular automated maintenance routine (VBScripts run on the file server by Windows Task Scheduler will suffice). Even if you do the archive, you really need to perform regular maintenance and backup.